# Migrate Old MySQL with 3 tables to JSON

Tags: mysql, database, firebase, nosql

I am working on migrating my PHP/MySQL data to Firebase, which only allows import via JSON. I made these 5 MySQL tables a few years ago and didn't do it correctly. I never officially set anything as a foreign key, so I was using separate queries instead of joins.

Now, I am attempting to write a script to move about 4000 combined rows. I'm using PHPMyAdmin and have all the standard features available there. I'd really appreciate any tips or hints in the right direction. Thanks ahead of time! :)

Here's a simplified version of my layout with all the necessary parts:

```
TABLE users
    - id (int, primary key)
    - username (varchar)

TABLE posts
    - id (int, primary key)
    - content (varchar)
    - userid (int, should be foreign key to users)

TABLE comments
    - id (int, primary key)
    - content (varchar)
    - userid (int, should be foreign key to users)
    - postid (int, should be foreign key to posts)

TABLE commentLikes
    - id (int, primary key)
    - likeValue (int)
    - commentid (int, should be foreign key to comments)
    - userid (int, should be foreign key to users)

TABLE postLikes
    - id (int, primary key)
    - likeValue (int)
    - postid (int, should be foreign key to posts)
    - userid (int, should be foreign key to users)
```

Basically, users on the site can create posts and comment on posts. Comments and posts can both be liked.

I mapped out what I would like the JSON documents to look like. I would have one type for users, and one type for posts.

```
Post JSON format
{
    id: 100,
    content: "A post by user 1",
    userid: 1,
    comments: [
        {
            content: "A comment by user 2",
            userid: 2,
            commentLikes: [
                {
                    likeValue: 1,
                    userid: 2
                },
                {
                    likeValue: -1,
                    userid: 3
                }        
            ]
        },
        {
            content: "A comment by user 3",
            userid: 3,
            commentsLikes: []
        }
    ],
    postLikes: [
        {
            likeValue: 1,
            userid: 2
        },
        {
            likeValue: -1,
            userid: 3
        }        
    ]
}

User JSON Format
{
    id: 1,
    username: "Bob"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this transformation? I understand that the MySQL is set up pretty badly. However, I cannot afford to lose this data. Here's a script that I wrote, but I don't believe it works. Even after the script works, how might I batch create these JSON files for import into Firebase?

```
SELECT p.*, c.content, c.userid, cL.likeValue, cL.userid, pL.likeValue, pL.userid 
FROM posts p, comments c, commmentLikes cL, postLikes pL 
WHERE c.postid = p.id OR pL.postid = p.id
```

If you've read til here, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Define classes for the data structure you require. Populate the objects with your data.  Verify the object structure meets your requirement and pass the object to json_encode. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - if you need to store them in files, use fwrite - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: @RyanRentfro ah that sounds along the right lines. For some reason, I've been looking at it from PHPMyAdmin but I will give classes and json_encode a shot. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should be able to export the view from PHPMyAdmin as an array then simply json_encode the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my installed version of PHPMyadmin, 4.2.7.1 I was able to directly export an entire table, or a view generated from a query as JSON.

If your version doesn't have JSON listed in the export format options just upgrade to any version that has the 'Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin'. Looks to be any version >= 3.5.1